# border-image shorthand syntax with LESS

Tags: css, less, border-image

I am trying to use `border-image` shorthand syntax in my CSS, for example:

```
border-image: url(border.png) 10 / 10px;
```

However, I am using LESS at the same time. In that situation, the slash is also the symbol of division, and that expression produces:

```
border-image: url(border.png) 1px;
```

I try to add a `fill` keyword into the statement just before the slash, and make the image transparent within the center area. However, this is not what I wanted, and I cannot add another slash for the `border-image-outset` property.

Using individual properties like `border-image-slice` is OK, but that doesn't work on some devices according to http://caniuse.com/#search=border-image. I am working on an Android project, and mobile compatibility is necessary here.

Any other solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Put the `/` within `~` like `~"/"` or put the entire value within it. That should solve it. Setting `strict-math` as `on` would also solve the problem but that would make every math operation require a brace around it and may affect other parts of your code.

Comment: Working fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/enry/7vvredp0/